# sql transfer data between databases tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Data Transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383057/sql-data-transfer)

I have my Dev database, and some times I add some data to tables and I want to upload it to prod. Is there a tool that allows transferring data between 2 databases?

Comment: And do you want to replace data in prod, or just add to it?

Comment: Scripts, Linked Server (SQL Server), mysqldump or a MySQL FEDERATED engine, Oracle data pump, Oracle export...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming MS SQL

[bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

OR

[SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)

Comment: I'm using Sql server. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to alex's choices you can use [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) or [SQL Data Compare by Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=redgate&gclid=CL_2lJD46qgCFcPrKgodMmo9uQ).